# codingbat string theEnd

Tags: java, string

Total noob question, why do when i type

```
if (front = true) return str.substring(0,1);
return str.substring(str.length()-1,str.length());
```

I got if true for both front.

Isn't it if it's not true, then it's false?

And also when i just change " = true" to " != false" the answer is correct

```
if (front != false) return str.substring(0,1);
return str.substring(str.length()-1,str.length());
```

isn't " = true" and " != false" the same thing?

Here's the link http://codingbat.com/prob/p162477

Comment: If you're using Eclipse for example, perhaps consider switching on *Possible accidental boolean assignment (e.g. 'if (a=b)'):* (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` for comparisons. `=` is an assignment.

Executing `if (front = true)` assigns `front` the value `true`.

Also the "return value" of an assignment is the assignment's value, which is why the "condition" `front = true` will always be true.

Also when checking whether a boolean variable's value is `true`, it's enough to write

```
if(front) {
```